# copy/reshape high dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with a shape like this

```
x.shape
(100, 1, 300, 300)
```

Think of this as 100 observations of grayscale images of size 300x300.
Grayscale images have only 1 channel, hence the second 1 in the shape.

I want to convert this to an array of RGB images, with 3 channels.
I want to just copy the grayscale image to the two other channels.

So the final shape would be (100, 3, 300, 300)

How can I do that?

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @Divakar sorry, forgot to accept. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
np.repeat(x,3,axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [8]: x = np.random.randint(11,99,(2,1,3,4))

In [9]: np.repeat(x,3,axis=1).shape
Out[9]: (2, 3, 3, 4)
```